# How do I use rand() with an enum?

Tags: c++, random, enums, switch-statement

Hello I'm beginning to learn c++ , I don't understand how enum works that well and I need help knowing how can I make the rand() working with enum

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "First part : Create an item. " << endl;
    int choice;

    int Fire = 25;
    int Water = 23;
    int Wind = 24;
    int Earth = 20;
    
    int WeaponNature = 0;
    
    enum NatureWeapons { Fire, Water, Wind, Earth}; // enum here if its wrong pls let me know ): 
    
   
    
    cout << "Enter the nature of weapon you want : " << endl;
    cout << " 1 - Fire " << endl;
    cout << " 2 - Water " << endl;
    cout << " 3 - Wind " << endl;
    cout << " 4 - Earth" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
        cout << "You picked fire."
        cout << " Power : " << Fire << endl;
        WeaponNature = Fire;
        break;
        
        case 2:
        cout << "You picked water." << endl;
        cout << " Power : " << Water << endl;
        WeaponNature = Water;
        break;
        
        case 3:
        cout << "You picked wind nature." << endl;
        cout << " Power : " << Wind << endl;
        WeaponNature = Wind;
        break;
        
        case 4:
        cout << "You picked earth nature." << endl;
        cout << " Power : " << Earth << endl;
        WeaponNature = Earth;
        break;
        
        default:
        cout << "Incorrect input. Your weapon will be : " << rand() // this is where i need help 
        
    }
    


}
```

When the default: runs in the switch() i wanted it to choose a random nature with rand(), please any help ): ?

Comment: enums in c++ are simply a convenient representation of a range of ints (0-3) in this case.

Comment: And how do I use rand() on default: ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As take from http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html:

> Printing Enums
>
> You might wonder what happens when you print out an enum: by default, you'll get the integer value of the enum. If you want to do something fancier than that, you'll have to handle it specially.

You would have to create another switch block converting the random integer into the proper value from the enum. Also, initialise a seed for your random number generator via `srand( time( NULL ) )`

Assign the rand value to WeaponNature as well.

Comment: Oh thanks , you and Phillip knocked some sense into me, now I get what an enum is , ty /case solved :D